# Matrix representations of Transformation with change of basis (Fraleigh Beauregard)

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I'm having problems understanding section 7.2 of FB's Linear Algebra, 3rd edition, and I can't find the solution online since no specific name is given to the matrices.

Sorry for the long explanation, but like I said I have no idea what the matrices are called.

> I think I actually more or less figured it out while typing this, but I'm still completely sure, and it'd be a waste just to not post after all that work. I would also still like to know if the $R_{B,B'}$ matrices have a name.

They talk about a matrix $R_{B,B'}$, which satisfies $T(\vec v)=R_{B,B'}\vec v_b$ for all $\vec v$ in V.

> It is the purpose of this section to study the effect that choosing different
>   bases for coordinatization has on the matrix representations of a linear
>   transformation. For simplicity, we shall derive our results in tenns of the
>   vector spaces R^n. They can then be carried over to other finite-dimension al
>   vector spaces using coordinatization isomorphisms.

They then give an example in whic a the differentiation transformation is projected on the reverse ordered P4:
$B=(x^4,x^3,x^2,x,1)$, and because here $kx^{k-1}$
$$R_{B,B'}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\4&0&0&0&0\\0&3&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

All pretty straight forward so far.

Then they introduce theorem 7.1:

> Let T be a linear transfonnation of a finite-dimensional vector space V
>   into itself, and let B and B' be ordered bases of V. Let RB and RB',.. be the
>   matrix representations of T relative to B and B', respectively. Then
>   $$R_{B'}=C^{-1}R_BC$$ where $C=C_{B',B}$ is the change-of-coordinates matrix from B' to B.
>   Consequently, RB' and RB are similar matrices.

So I'm not really sure what the different RB and RB' here represent, so I check their examples to find out:

First a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1+x_2+x_3,x_1+x_2,x_3$)
$$B=([1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,1])$$

They find RB by putting B in column vector form, and augment the matrix with T(bn).

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}1&1&0&2&2&2\\1&0&1&2&1&1\\0&1&1&0&1&1\end{array}\right]$$
They row reduce and say the right part is RB, fine, and the go on to find C.

Now the confounding part.
They finally use two different bases in the next example with polynomial spaces.

$$T:P_2 \rightarrow P_2 | T(p(x))=p(x-1)$$
Consider two ordered bases $B=(x^2,x,1)$ and $B'=(x^2,x+1,x^2-x)$

They immediately write down:
$$T(x^2)=(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1, t(x)=x-1, t(1)=1$$
$$R_B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-2&1&0\\1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
As this is with respect to a basis of E3 of polynomials, row reduction is unnecessary.
But why is the result of the transformation written vertically in the third example, but horizontally in the second?

Comment: I don't see what you mean - it looks vertical in the second example; the third entry in the first column of the augmented part is $0$, which is the third component of $T([1,1,0])$, not the first component of $T([0,1,1])$. The $R_{B,B'}$ are matrices of a linear transformation with respect to the bases $B$ and $B'$, I'm not aware of a shorter name than that.

Comment: The $R_B$ and $R_{B'}$ could be written more fully as $R_{B,B}$ and $R_{B',B'}$ to match the notation from before - this time the transformation is from a vector space to itself, so it makes more sense to only choose one basis. (I don't know if this is what you meant when you said you weren't sure what $R_B$ and $R_{B'}$ represent, but maybe it's helpful to say anyway!).

Comment: It does help, it was one of the little niggles the authors didn't explain, and I wasn't quite sure of yet.
I meant that the right part seems to have the results of the transformation horizontal:
$x1+x2+x3 is (2,2,2)

Comment: Oh, that's probably not a useful way of thinking about it (although it is true). The procedure is to write $T(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_{ij}v_i$ for some constants $\lambda_j$, for each $v_j$ in the basis $B$, and then the $j$-th column of $R_B$ consists of the $\lambda_{ij}$s. So each column should tell you the action of the transformation on a single basis vector. I think there might be a typo in the second example; $B$ and $B'$ are the same, and $R_B$ isn't correct. This matrix is actually $R_{B,B''}$, where $B''=(x^2,x,1)$.

Comment: Ya, fixed the typo.
Right, I was looking at it from the wrong perspective. I got it now. So $(1,1,0)\rightarrow (x_1+x_2+x_3,x_1+x_2,x_3)=(2,2,0)$. Need to work on more transformations to attain consistency. I was just looking at how to make the example make sense, which is sloppy. Thanks.

Comment: OK - that makes more sense. (In my previous comment, $R_{B,B''}$ should just say $R_{B''}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarise some comments into an answer, since they seem to have been helpful. Given a linear map $T\colon V\to W$, and bases $B=\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ and $B'=\{w_1,\dotsc,w_m\}$ of $V$ and $W$, the matrix $R_{B,B'}$ of $T$ with respect to these bases is the $m\times n$ matrix with $(i,j)$-th entry $\lambda_{ij}$, where $$T(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_{ij}w_i.$$

So to compute it, apply $T$ to each element of $B$, write the result as a linear combination of the vectors in $B'$, and write the cofficients in a column of the matrix.

In the second example above, you have a map $T\colon V\to V$, and $V$ has basis $B=([1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,1])$. You have

\begin{align*}
T([1,1,0])&=[2,2,0]=2[1,1,0]\\
T([1,0,1])&=[2,1,1]=[1,1,0]+[1,0,1]\\
T([0,1,1])&=[2,1,1]=[1,1,0]+[1,0,1]
\end{align*}

so the matrix is

$$R_{B,B}=R_B=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

The row reduction technique gives you a way of computing this starting from

$$R_{B,E}=\begin{pmatrix}2&2&2\\2&1&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

where $E=([1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1])$ is the standard basis, but you can do it directly as above.